# Как отключить сортировку товаров в Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

Встала задача, чтобы на страницах с товарами, товары были на определенных местах. Есть массив товаров c нужными id, где ключи 0,1,2.. - позиции товара на странице. Товаров на странице 30, всего товаров 300, и нужно сделать так, чтобы товар с ключом 31, был первым на 2-ой странице,300 - в конце на последней странице и т.д. Сортировки по id, свойствам и т.д. не подходят. Можно ли решать данную проблему штатными функциями, не обращаясь к БД напрямую?
В getlist в сортировке используется значение по умолчанию, если передавать null или неверную сортировку.

Comment: То что вы написали это и есть сортировка по ID или у вас ключи 0,1,2 это не ID элемента а значения какого-то свойства? Так и делайте сортировку по этому свойству. Я не совсем пойму что вы делаете и почему не получается. Пишите что есть id и по id надо сортировать, но сортировка по id вам почему-то не подходит. Зачем лезть в getlist, когда есть настройка компонента вывода товаров.

Comment: я написал, ключи -номер позиции товара на странице. массив имеет вид [0] => 1313,[1] => 1314 и т.д. Сортировка по id не подходит, т.к. товаров есть цена и количество, и если цена =0 или количесвто = 0, то он его выведет не в конце, как я хочу, а согласно его позиции в сортировке. Похоже в 1 getlist не получиться так сделать, надо напрямую к бд обращатся.

Comment: Тогдаи в вызов компонента отображающего список товаров вы должны в параметры содержащие `SORT` передать параметр массива который содержит ключи.

Comment: В один getList передайте, только в параметре `order` укажите массив примерно так `array('PRICE' => 'ASC', 'KOLVO' => 'ASC')`.